# Jboss - CAS without filter

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, cas

I jave jboss EAP 6 with cas deployed on it and a helloworld as well. What I need to do is to force authentication on helloworld app, somehow without using filters in web.xml. In my jboss I've put a security domain "myrealm":

```
 <security-domain name="myrealm" cache-type="default">
                <authentication>
                    <login-module code="org.jasig.cas.client.jaas.CasLoginModule" flag="required">
                        <module-option name="ticketValidatorClass" value="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator"/>
                        <module-option name="casServerUrlPrefix" value="https://135.243.36.205:8443/cas"/>
                        <module-option name="tolerance" value="20000"/>
                        <module-option name="defaultRoles" value="user"/>
                        <module-option name="roleAttributeNames" value="memberOf,eduPersonAffiliation,authorities"/>
                        <module-option name="principalGroupName" value="CallerPrincipal"/>
                        <module-option name="roleGroupName" value="Roles"/>
                        <module-option name="cacheAssertions" value="true"/>
                        <module-option name="cacheTimeout" value="480"/>
                    </login-module>
                </authentication>
            </security-domain>
```

and now I just want to force this application to use this realm. In my application's jboss-web.xml, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<jboss-web>  
    <security-domain>myrealm</security-domain>  
</jboss-web>
```

What am I missing, because if I access my application it doesn't redirect me to my CAS login page, it just goes to index.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an valve-Entry in your jboss-web.xml

```
<valve>
    <class-name>com.foo.MyAuthenticator
    </class-name>
</valve>
```

MyAuthenticator is an implementation of org.apache.catalina.Authenticator.

In my environment, I modified the [FormAuthenticator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.web/jbossweb/7.5.7.Final/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/FormAuthenticator.java#FormAuthenticator) to read the samlArtifactId and serviceUrl instead of username/password.

In your web.xml you need to add the login-Method, which is the AuthenticatorName without "Authenticator". If you name your authenticator MyAuthenticator you need to add:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>MY</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

As far as i know there is no existing authenticator for jboss, so you need to create your own authenticator implementation. Or you can use [filters](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/casc/using+casfilter), which work also on jboss.

If you need to write your own authenticator, you should become familiar with [JAAS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jaas/JAASRefGuide.html). You can reuse the login-module (you named it my 'myrealm') with the jasig classes. Start to read and understand [FormAuthenticator](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.web/jbossweb/7.5.7.Final/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/FormAuthenticator.java#FormAuthenticator) and then modify it, to read the serviceURL and SamlArtifact from the request instead of username password and pass the values to the callback handler.

Comment: I guess this is my only option, implementing my own authenticator, but I really don't get how to do this. Can you guide me, please?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take care, this isn't a task which can be done quick. Luckily, there is a good documentation and source code.

Comment: Thank you! I'll see what I can do.