# Jboss SSO with CAS

Tags: jboss, single-sign-on, cas

How can I make to work JBOSS SSO with Jasig CAS so they would work together?
I have some applications that can only work with jboss sso, but I also need to work with Jasig CAS, so I, somehow, have to make them work together. How can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think I could help and I know jasig pretty good, but I don't understand your question :-) What is "your" understanding of jboss sso? Do you need some values from "jboss sso"  which can't be provided by jasig? Is there another login-mask if you use "jboss sso"?

Comment: So, I have an ear with 20+ wars (so it's a big application) that it's working in a cluster with jboss sso. Now, I have another portal that is already configured to work with CAS. What I need to do is to make this 2 big things work together (I need sso on everything). My problem is that I can't add filters in this big ear with multiple wars, so I was thinking that maybe I can make CAS work with jboss sso.

Comment: Sounds like you need your own authenticator as i described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378824/jboss-cas-without-filter/31384402#31384402